# openssl and libsodium export restrictions

Tags: software

When going on the [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) it clearly states that openssl is subject to export restriction because it uses strong encryption.

Looking at the [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) page I cannot find anything like this.

Why? Are the restriction different for libsodium or did they just not mention it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libsodium is hosted in France, and the lead developer appears to be French.  That means the project can completely ignore US-based export restrictions.  OpenSSL, on the other hand, is based in the US and so is subject to those restrictions.